# Pandas adding a scoring column based on multiple criteria

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Let's say I have the following dataframe:

```
  Priority   Color Risk
1        1   Green    8
2        9     Red   10
3        5  Orange    4
```

I would like to add a column 'Score' which calculates a score for each row based on multiple conditions related to the other columns. For example, the conditions and scoring could be:

- If 'Priority' column > 5, add 1 point, otherwise 0 points
- If 'Color' column == 'Red', add 1 point, otherwise 0 points
- If 'Risk' column > 7, add 1 point, otherwise 0 points

In this case, row 1 would get 1 point, row 2 would get 3 points and row 3 would get 0 points.

Does anyone know how I could achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can sum boolean conditions converted to ints with `.astype`:

```py
df['score'] = ( (df['Priority'] > 5).astype(int)
                + (df['Color'] == 'Red').astype(int) 
                + (df['Risk'] > 7).astype(int) )
```

```
   Priority   Color  Risk  score
1         1   Green     8      1
2         9     Red    10      3
3         5  Orange     4      0
```

Comment: This is explicit and simple; OP should accept this answer.